# Fail to query a list corresponding another value in ADD ROW action

Tags: oracle-apex

Please Help...

I am using Oracle Apex.

I created the FORM page with Master Details form, it has CW_ORDER and CW_SALESLINE table. There also is a CW_INVENTORY table.

When user press "Add Row" button, there will show two list boxes for choosing which 'TYPE' as Product type" and 'INV_ID' as Product Description".

TYPE as Product Type is configured "Select List(static LOV)" 
with List of Value (STATIC:Hardware;Hardware,Software;Software)
User can choose 'Hardware' or 'Software' only.

INV_ID as Product Description is configured "Select List(query based LOV)
with List of Value (select description, inv_id from cw_inventory where cw_inventory.type = :type)

I want that when user chooses Product Type value such as 'Hardware' and then Product Description can list only the type of Hardware items for choosing instead of all items are listed.

In CW_Inventoty has a 'TYPE' column, its value is Hardware or Software.

I think the (select description, inv_id from cw_inventory where cw_inventory.type = :type) something wrong.

Please advise. Thank you so much .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your above requirement,
                                                                                                      you want to use cascading select list concept here in tabular form.
refer [Cascading select list on tabular form](http://dbswh.webhop.net/apex/f?p=BLOG:READ:0::::ARTICLE:2003800346210117) for more details.

Comment: I am a beginner of APEX.I felt very difficult and not fully understand.  Would you show me more simple about that ?

Comment: create demo example on apex.oracle.com and post details of workspace,username and password. i will look into that

Comment: Thank you so much... workspace is DATABASE_ENGINEERING. LOGIN is yuetkui@gmail.com and password is 123abc123. The application is CW_COMP1639_210411. Please go to tab Order in the application --> click edit button on any existing order. Please don't change anything on existing tables. Thank you so much...

Comment: look at your application i've implemented cascading select list in page 11 or in tab "ORDER"

Comment: I has looked your modification. Great !!! thank you so much. I will try to study about it.

Comment: I also need to modifiy Page 15 "Serviceline" with same configuration Page 11. I did everything on Page 15 except On Demand process. How to create the On Demand process for Page 15. Please teach me. Thank you ....

Comment: I attempted to create on demand process on page 15 but very strange. When I right clicked the mouse on Processes on page 15 then I select my tabular form, the "Run on demand process" icon disappeared. so i could not complete creating "On demand process".

Comment: go to create process, select process point as a on demand process, do not select Tabular form while creating on demand process. your credentials not works to look into your workspace.

Comment: I tried before. but i got error message "To Create an on-demand page process, at least one application level process must be created with the type 'ON-DEMAND'.

Comment: My steps, right clicked any process icon on page 15 then choose Create -->  choose Run On Demand Process (Tabular Form unselect) --> Name : GET_DATA -->Sequence = 50 --> Point : On Demand - Run this process when requested by AJAX then press next button , i got the error message. I think i missed something ?

Comment: give different name to process because all steps are corrects

Comment: I changed name to GET_DATA2 but result was same. I did not create G_TEMP because you did. Can G_TEMP be reused ?

Comment: Would you mind that please teach me you how to create an on demand process for that? Thanks you ...

Comment: I created the On demand process successful now. But cannot query result on list box.. I am thinking.

Comment: I have checked everything, it seems to be no problem but the list box is still keeping "Loading....". what is wrong...

Comment: The problem has been solved after all. typing mistake cause keeping "Loading.... Now is okay. Thank you Pars.